# rosmsg show Num error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosmsg, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the ROS Tutorial ''Creating a ROS msg and srv'' and meet a problem.
When I type

```
$ rosmsg show Num
```

It shows

```
Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: /home/xxx/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg/Num.msg: Invalid declaration: int 64 num
```

can anybody explain this error? thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318982/rosmsg-show-num-error/) by [Leo Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/40542/leo-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you have an extra space in your `Num.msg` message definition. It should be `int64 num` not `int 64 num`.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3